# Logout from jail

Tags: freebsd, jails, freenas

I'm trying to use FreeNAS on my office along with Syncthing, and some things are giving me headache.

FreeNAS installed Syncthing as a jail, and I did the jexec command to login into the jail, but now I can't figure out a way to login back into my server. I'm as `root@syncthing` instead of being in `root@freenas`. How do I undo the jexec on the shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were unable to just?
$ exit

Comment: I was trying to do $ quit